# Yii cannot Instantiate controller

Tags: controller, yii

As I see if we want to instantiate a Model (for example named `Post`), we just have to call:

```
$post = new Post();
```

Now, I also want to instantiate a `Controller` (for example named `Post`, and php file for this controller named `PostController.php`). So I use this code:

```
$postController = new PostController();
```

However, I get an error when running this code.

I did some searching and found that it should be like the following to instantiate:

```
$postController = Yii::app()->createController('post/index');
```

It runs correctly. But I still wonder why the first approach doesn't work?

Comment: It would be helpful if you include *which* error you're getting.

Answer (score 6):

Answering your exact question "why the first approach doesn't work".
The folder `/protected/controller` is **NOT** in "include path" of the project.

Just add `'import'=>array('application.controllers.*')` into your config file or use
`include(Yii::app()->getBasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'PostController.php');`

just before creating an object of PostController. Ah and creating new controller requires a name for this controller, so it should be something like

`$controller = new PostController('post_controller');`

I would like to point out that this type of controller creation is useless in Yii, as you are creating a controller completely separated from project, so it will be *almost* useless. As you noted, the correct way to create controller is through `Yii::app()->createController()`

Comment: Johnatan, you saved me from being headache with just one simple sentence. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lebarn it would be really nice if you could accept the answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
 $controller = Yii::app()->controller;
```

This returns your current controller for request.

Also see docs here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#controller-detail

Comment: Thank you, Korotovsky, but could you explain why $postController = new PostController(); didn't work? I simply follow creating new Controller Class object.

Comment: You can't do that, because there's a complicated scheme of initializing and validating rights.