# Yii application where the createController() method reside?

Tags: controller, yii

I am using this code to create a new Yii Controller:

```
$postController= Yii::app()->createController('post/index');
```

It returns an `array` – not a `Controller` object as I was expecting.

I tried to find the `createController()` method inside the application API, but didn't see it.

Comment: It seems that this double of previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11772160/1563234 link to my previous answer.

Comment: read the documentation please, you can easily find the [method there](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#createController-detail)

Answer (score 0):

It is in the CWebApplication in the framework ..
If you mean to change the method, I advice you NOT to modify anything in the framework, you can build your own classes by inheriting from existing ones and overriding the functions to get the desired results.